# Banded Rows for Excel Table Design are Inconsistent When Sorted

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010, excel-tables

I am tabling a lot of data and using Excel's "Format as Table" function to do so easily and quickly. Furthermore, I would like to sort the data from Newest to Oldest, because the data was not originally available that way. Long story short, I want to make PDFs after sorting my data nicely, bu my table's banded rows keep getting jumbled up. The rows are not banded every other row, they instead seem to do so randomly. I have exhausted my options trying to fix this - even unformatting the table and rerunning the format as table function. Below are photos of this issue:

Before Sorting:

[image: Before Sorting]

After Sorting:

[image: After Sorting]

Comment: why not first sort them, and apply the format as table afterwards?

Comment: I was using the table format to make the table data easy to sort in the first place. I have many tables like this and would rather not go back and unformat all data, sort, then reformat. Thanks.

Comment: you can apply filters without formatting it as a table to get your sort filter options.  you can also apply conditional formatting to the area under your header row.  You would need to set up the colouring and the formula first, but it should not be affected by your sorting depending on how you do it.  you could use `=isodd(row())` and `=isEVEN(ROW())` and apply a colour to each result.  Then apply the two conditional format equations to all your data cells.